# Add Color to Leaflet Marker based on Values

Tags: r, leaflet

I have a sample data for various cities across globe and their population, density etc., as below:

```
structure(
  list(
    V1 = 0:4,
    City = c("Malé", "Manila", "Bogor",
             "Titagarh", "Baranagar"),
    Population = c(1539041, 16607142, 8660344,
                   1242136, 2507686),
    `Area (km²)` = c(19561, 38553, 21565, 3247,
                     7127),
    `Area (mi²)` = c("0.755", "14.88", "8.32", "1.25", "2.75"),
    `Density (/km²)` = c(78683L, 43079L, 40169L, 38337L, 35220L),
    `Density (/mi²)` = c(203846, 111576, 104037, 99293, 91220),
    Country = c("Maldives", "Philippines", "Indonesia", "India",
                "India"),
    latitude = c(4.175, 14.5995,-6.5944, 22.7427, 22.642),
    longitude = c(73.5093, 120.9842, 106.7892, 88.3767, 88.3724)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,-5L),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"),
  .internal.selfref = < pointer:0x000001d59528aec0 >
)
```

To populate the map I've used the following code:

```
city_icon<-makeAwesomeIcon(
  icon = "home",
  library = "glyphicon",
  markerColor = "red",
  iconColor = "black",
  spin = FALSE,
  extraClasses = NULL,
  squareMarker = FALSE,
  iconRotate = 0,
  fontFamily = "monospace",
  text = NULL
)

leaflet(cities) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addAwesomeMarkers(
    ~longitude, ~latitude, 
    popup = ~paste0("<b>", City, "</b><br>Population: ", Population),
    icon = city_icon
  ) %>%
  addControl(
    html = tags$div(
      style = "text-align:center",
      tags$h1("Top 50 Cities"),
      tags$p("Population Map")
    ),
    position = "topright"
  )
```

[image: Top 50 Cities]

**How to change color of the markers based on values (Population)?**